# difficulty in singleton swift

Tags: ios, swift, singleton

I am trying to use singleton in my `swift` app.
I have a class which i used in `ObjectiveC` and now i am using it in `swift` using bridging-header...

In singleton class here is my code...

`SharedManger.h` file

```
 +(SharedManager *)sharedInstance;

 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *dictobject;
```

`SharedManger.m` file

```
 + (id)sharedInstance
 {
      static SharedManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
      @synchronized(self)
      {
         if (sharedMyManager == nil)
           {

              static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

               dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

                  sharedMyManager = [self loadInstance];

            });  
       }
  }

  return sharedMyManager;
}

+(instancetype)loadInstance
{
     NSData* decodedData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: [SharedManager filePath]];

  if (decodedData)
   {
       SharedManager* sharedData = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decodedData];
       return sharedData;
   }

   return [[SharedManager alloc] init];
 }
```

in  `viewcontroller.swift`

```
 class var sharedInstance: viewcontroller {
    struct Static {
        static var onceToken: dispatch_once_t = 0
        static var instance: viewcontroller? = nil
    }
    dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
        Static.instance = viewcontroller()
    }
    return Static.instance!
}

func sharedManager()->SharedManager{
    return SharedManager.sharedInstance()
}
```

**Question:**

1. So this is right approach in swift or any better approach is there?

**Edit:**
storyboard hierarchy is `navbar -> loginVC -> VC1 ->VC2`
as @Schemetrical says...i used his approach as `singleton`....it works fine when i comes from `loginVC` i can access data from `singleton`....
but after one time login my root view controller changes and comes from `VC1` and that time it display empty `singleton`....why is it so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swift 1.2 makes it really easy to create singletons. The static instance will be initialised only once and dictObject will be available for other classes to retrieve.

```
class SharedManager {

    static let sharedInstance = SharedManager()

    var dictObject = // some default value

}
```

Comment: ok...so i just need to make one .swift file instead of my 2 objectiveC files

Comment: Yes indeed. By default, within your project scope, all variables are available, but you can choose to make them private or public.

Comment: Could you rephrase that?

Comment: I wanted you to repeat the previous question because I didn't understand what you were trying to say ._.

Comment: as in question , i have `viewcontroller.swift` file ...so am i write right code in it or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77171/discussion-between-bhavin-and-schemetrical).